# Android : How to open MenuInflater with a button

Tags: android, button, menu, imagebutton

I want an option menu on the top right corner in my activity, it should be like a drop down menu if possible, i tried this one, it didn't work for me!!!!

```
ImageButton imagebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu);

imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342127/android-how-to-open-menuinflater-with-a-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342127/android-how-to-open-menuinflater-with-a-button)

Comment: first return `true` from `onCreateOptionsMenu()`...

Comment: @Gopal Rao i tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Do you want similar like https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D ?

Comment: to open Options Menu programatically on a button click, call `openOptionsMenu()`...

Comment: Could you please correct my code instead,

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my question and it worked for me:

```
ImageButton imagebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu);
Imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(); 

@Override
public void onClick(View p1)
{
    openOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);        

    return true;
}
```